# unable to push service on docker registry on aws

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I need some help , I am trying to push the service in the docker registry on the aws
and registry is running on port 8000 and trying to push using command push

**localhost:8000/myapp.service:0.1**

error i am getting is
"http://localhost:8000/v2/": read tcp 127.0.0.1:60222->127.0.0.1:8000: read: connection reset by peer

Comment: Where are you running what command exactly? What registry is running on port 8000, on what machine?

Comment: on Ec2 instance , connecting from ssh

Comment: And where do you expect localhost to point to? Your local machine? No. The ECS instance itself? Yes.

Comment: yes you are right, i am pointing localhost EC2 instance.

Comment: yes you are right , I am pointing localhost to EC2 instance

Comment: I am creating docker tar file using command docker save -o service.tar and copying from my local machine to ec2 instance then i am pushing the service.